# Solidity function arguments default storage types

Tags: solidity

What are the memory storage types of the arguments by default? I cannot find any doc about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#data-location) of reference types.

The data location specifies whether you want to work with the value in non-persistent `memory`, use it as a read-only user input (`calldata`), or read/write the value in persistent `storage`.

Comment: thanks, but if we do not specify any data location. What are the default assigned ones?

Comment: @Psartek You don't specify data location of value types (`uint`, `bool`, `address` - see the complete list in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#value-types))... There's no default data location of reference types. If you define a reference type without its location, the compiler throws an error and doesn't compile.